# Fine uploader TokenMismatchException in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

How I can add this input:

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
```

to FineUploader without creating a form?

Comment: Checkout @Youmdingding's answer. It does work to me.

Answer (score 8):

You have probably solved your problem since but this might help other people coming accross this thread. The following worked for me :

in `<head>` :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Then initialize you fineUploader as follow :

```
var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: "path/to/your/server",
        customHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question, @Jensej? To me, it does. Consider to accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not html form then the input will not be sent as there no no posting form event. 
Alternative option is to have the CSRF token in the headers like

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

Comment: look: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HPhmv5nf
but I still have this same error: 
`TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:`

Comment: Is the X-CSRF-TOKEN catched if you print the Request object with dd($request) ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$('#fineUploader').fineUploaderS3({
   request: {
       endpoint: options.endpoint,
       accessKey: options.accessKey
   },
   signature: {
       endpoint: '/fineUploaderEndpoint',
       version: 4,
       customHeaders: {
           "X-CSRF-Token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
       }
   }
```